# Jquery: how to toggle/slide one div over another so it takes its place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

My goal is to to create an animation (css / jquery), so green box slides (grows) over red one (red one is fixed).
Then toggle it back : green shrinks and red comes back again.

Using ("#green").css("wdith") makes the red one being pushed and I want to avoid that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<style>
.green {
    width:400px;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    height:320px;
}
.red{
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:320px;   
}
</style>


<div>
<div id="green" class="green">eezez</div>
<div id="red" class="red">eezez</div>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#action").click(function() {
            // toggle so green grows and takes red place (red does not move)
            // toggle so green shrinks and so red takes his initial place again
        });
    });
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sj575/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a float instead. Try this:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Sj575/1/)**

```
.green {
    width:400px;
    background-color:green;
    height:320px;
    float:left;
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
    height:320px;
}
#container {
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
<div id="container">
    <div id="green" class="green">eezez</div>
    <div id="red" class="red">eezez</div>
</div>
<button id="action">Toggle Green !</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 $('#green').slideToggle("fast");
```

then add css property

```
   .green {
    width:400px;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:320px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/Sj575/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Like j08691 I also added float:left to both divs and I added display:block and clear both to the button, otherwise it would too be on the left

```
<body>
<style>
.green {
width:400px;
background-color:green;
float: left;
height:320px;
}

.red{
width:200px;
background-color:red;
float: left;
height:320px;   
}

#action{
display: block;
clear:both;
margin-top:2em;
}
</style>


<div>
    <div id="green" class="green">eezez</div>
    <div id="red" class="red">eezez</div>    
</div>

<button id="action" >Toggle Green !</button>
```

Now what I did was make 2 different functions,to make sure the button wouldn't invoke both events I used the preventDefault(); method. I used animate to increase width and decrease the red using hide() to make it disappear, once you click on 'action' the green will disappear and the red div will take its place

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#action").one('click', toggleGreen);
            // toggle so green grows and takes red place (red does not move)
            function toggleGreen(){
                $("#green").animate({
                    width:'600px'
                });
                $("#red").animate({
                    width:'100px'
                }).hide(2000);
                preventDefault();
            }

        $("#action").on('click', function(){
            // toggle so green shrinks and so red takes his initial place again
            $("#green").hide(2000);
            $("#red").animate({
                width:'600px'
            }).show(3000);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps!